# Powershell REG LOAD command not working

Tags: powershell, registry

Windows 7, in Powershell (running as admin), running the following command on an offline user:

```
& REG LOAD HKLM\CHANGEUSER c:\users\testuser\ntuser.dat
Write-Host Loaded with result $?
```

Result: **False**. On inspection of the key using regedit, it has NOT been loaded. Note: HKLM\Changeuser is not precreated.

---

If I use the same command from a command prompt (as admin), it is all fine:

```
REG LOAD HKLM\CHANGEUSER c:\users\testuser\ntuser.dat
```

Result: **The command completed successfully**, and the file has been loaded into the registry.

Why is it not loading into the registry when using powershell? I have attempted with and without the call operator (&), but get the same result.

Comment: Are you running as admin in _both_ cases?

Comment: Yes, both Powershell and Command Prompt state "Administrator:" at the top (Updated question to reflect this)

Comment: `.\REG LOAD HKLM\CHANGEUSER c:\users\testuser\ntuser.dat`

Comment: Works for me. What does `Get-Command reg` show?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers output shows "Application, reg.exe, C:\Windows\system32\reg.exe". There is no PS error when I run the command (so the command is found), but the hive is not loaded.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen ".\REG" give PS error "not recognized as the name of a cmdlet..."

Comment: The command looks OK. Can you read the file (`cat c:\users\testuser\ntuser.dat -Encoding Byte | select -First 3`)? Did you verify that it isn't already loaded elsewhere when you run the command. Also try logging what's happening with [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor).

Comment: inexplicably, it has now started working. I don't know why or how; no changes have been made to the test DAT file I'm using or to PS - not even a reboot. *Confused*. In any case, we can close this - appreciate all your input and apologies for taking your time. This is clearly not a PS issue.

Answer (score 1):

I would not attach the hive to HKLM.  You're supposed to attach it to HKEY_USERS (HKU).  That's what it's for.

Try:

```
reg.exe load HKU\Changeuser c:\users\testuser\ntuser.dat
Write-Host Loaded with result $?
```

You can access it like so:

```
Set-Location Registry::\HKEY_USERS\Changeuser
```

If you want a PowerShell drive (HKEY_USERS normally doesn't have one) you can use:

```
New-PSDrive -Name HKU -PSProvider Registry -Root HKEY_USERS; 
Set-Location HKU:
```

---

To expand, I've scheduled this with Task Scheduler running as a service account and as the local SYSTEM account using `at.exe` and I got nothing but success.  I even tried HKLM, and had success.  It's not clear to me what you're doing, but I don't have enough information anymore for why it's failing.

Comment: Whilst it is true it is a user hive, I don't particularly mind where it is loaded, provided I can access it to do offline edits. Unfortunately, selecting HKU makes no different - the same problem occurs. At the moment, I cannot see why it is not loading using the command in PS. If I can get more information, I will, but it's a normal NTUSER.dat, and I have full admin.