# Set User Environment Variable from Powershell running as SYSTEM

Tags: windows, powershell, environment-variables

Background (OS: Windows 10):

- I have Powershell script that runs(in background) as `SYSTEM`
- Through Powershell script I need to set both Machine and Logged-in User Environment Variables
- Machine Variables are set using `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('NAME', 'Value', 'Machine')` and works as-expected
- User Variables set using `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('NAME1', 'Value1', 'User')` does not work for End user accounts as the process runs as SYSTEM
- Powershell script execution needs at least one user logged in and this is working fine

I am able to find the logged in user with:
`$current_user = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem).UserName.Split('\')[1]`

I tried using Registry update to set logged-in User Variables but this does not work as expected:
`Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Environment' -Name 'NAME2' -Value 'Value2' -Force`

How can I set Logged-In User Env Variable from powershell script running as SYSTEM?

Comment: Search for "powershell impersonate user", that might bring you on track.

Comment: I don't think you need to impersonate, you just need to load the user hive into the current registry, see e.g.: [Powershell REG LOAD command not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35134100/1701026). Make sure you also **UNLOAD the hive** when you done!. For troubleshooting under the SYSTEM account see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51612478/1701026). Also note that you probably have to reload you user session to apply the changes you made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to set a registry value for the currently logged on user (which is not the one that runs the code), you need to find the users SID.

Try this:

```
# get the domain and username for the currently logged on user
$domain, $userName = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem).UserName -split '\\', 2
# next, get the SID for that current user
$user = [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]::new($domain, $userName)
$sid  = $user.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).Value

# set the registry value for this user.
Set-ItemProperty -Path "Registry::HKEY_USERS\$sid\Environment" -Name 'NAME2' -Value 'Value2' -Type String

# See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registryvaluekind?redirectedfrom=MSDN
# for other RegistryValueKind values for parameter Type
```

Answer (score 3):

For troubleshooting scripts running under the SYSTEM account, I am recommend using [PSExec](https://learn.microsoft.com/sysinternals/downloads/psexec), see: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51612478/1701026).
If you user's registry hive is not yet loaded, you need to **load** (*and* **Unload** it when you're done), see: [Powershell REG LOAD command not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35134100/1701026).

To find the user's hive (the path is identified by the user's SID) and set the environment variable:

```
$UserHive = Get-ChildItem -Path 'Registry::\HKEY_USERS' |
    Where-Object {(Test-Path "Registry::$_\Volatile Environment") -and (Get-ItemProperty "Registry::$_\Volatile Environment").USERNAME -eq $Username}

Set-ItemProperty -Path "Registry::$UserHive\Environment" -Name 'NAME2' -Value 'Value3' -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accepted answer, if you are wondering how to get the SID for one of the local system accounts like `SYSTEM` refer to the table below or follow [this link](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Well-known%20Security%20Identifiers) for complete list of [Well Known SIDs](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Well-known%20Security%20Identifiers):

| SID | Name | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| S-1-5-18 | Local System | A service account (SYSTEM) that is used by the operating system. |
| S-1-5-19 | NT Authority | Local Service |
| S-1-5-20 | NT Authority | Network Service |

> To create a user variable for the local `SYSTEM` user the command would be as follows:

```
# set environment variable 'NAME2' for the local SYSTEM user
Set-ItemProperty -Path "Registry::HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18\Environment" -Name 'NAME2' -Value 'Value2' -Type String
```